# SMTP mails being rejected by receiver

Tags: smtp

I run a custom webshop where my system sends out different notifications. Unfortunately yesterday I started receiving a lot of rejected emails. It's not all emails being rejected, only a specific kind.

In the example below I've received a response from Google, but I have the same problem with other mail servers.

What can be wrong? I've searched all over, and I'm clueless.. (PS: Masked some server info)

```
From: MAILER-DAEMON@******.server.com (Mail Delivery System)
Date: 23. jun 2011 14.57.18 CEST
To: me@********.com
Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender

This is the mail system at host ******.server.com.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

 The mail system

<****.****@gmail.com>: host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[209.85.143.27] said:
   550 Action not taken (in reply to end of DATA command)
Reporting-MTA: dns; ******.server.com
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 573DF7E0F1
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; me@******.com
Arrival-Date: Thu, 23 Jun 2011 14:57:17 +0200 (CEST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; ****.****@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 Action not taken

From: Website.com <sales@****.dk>
Date: 23. jun 2011 14.57.17 CEST
To: ****.****@gmail.com
Subject: Amount refunded to your account - 40700

... HTML content here ....
```

Comment: "Its not all emails being rejected, only a specific kind" - what kind? Sounds like a big clue. It would help if you were less vague here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mail server is not autorized to send mail for the specify domain. It's look like a reverse dns lookup from the server whoe send the mail

Try this tool http://www.mxtoolbox.com

Comment: I have now setup an rDNS, and in addition I enclosed a text/plain version of the email - that fixed it basically.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually send the original email? You may be the victim of backscatter spam? Your mail server logs should help you determine whether the original email came from your server(s).

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(e-mail)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_job